# Word spacing with a navigation menu in CSS, Dreamweaver

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver, nav

I'm very new to Dreamweaver, CSS and HTML. So I apologise if there's any obvious mistakes or solutions.

I'm trying to figure out how to separate words in my navigation menu. Because they always seem to be centred. I've tried adding "word-spacing" and other adjustments but wasn't able to come to a solution.

Just wondering if anyone's able to offer any suggestions in how I can fix this.

Any help is much appreciated,

Thank you.

CSS

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 100px;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  text-color: white;
  font: Helvetica;
  font-size: 100%;
  outline: 0 none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li id="nav-products"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li id="nav-contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li id="nav-about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it's because your li width is 100%, remove that, remove the float left and add display:inline-block;

Comment: Do yourself a favour, move away from DW it's terrible. I used it once upon a time, glad i moved over to Sublime which then made me move into PHPStorm.

Comment: @Option I'm creating a website for my collage work, and they only have Dreamweaver CS6 on their PCs. But if I continue web design after collage, I'll be sure to take a look at those.

Comment: The program doesn't matter. I could code a site in phpstorm for somebody using DW it'd still work :) It's just functionality etc. Deffo recommend phpstorm though but it does cost each year :)

Comment: @Pete Thanks for that, they're now evenly spaced horizontally on the left side of the page. May I ask how I can centre the words, and space them out from there? My aim is to have the words evenly spaced horizontally at the top of the page. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Option Does look a lot nicer, CS6 is starting to look a bit dated now. I'm lucky enough to get most of CS6 for free with my collage.

Comment: If you did what I said in my comment - it should be evenly spaced at the top of the page - not on the left: https://jsfiddle.net/jdq2ajvt/.  If you need spacing between them, add some padding.  I have also added box sizing so your nav is not 200px wider than the page: https://jsfiddle.net/jdq2ajvt/3/

Comment: @Pete Yes, my bad. Hope you don't mind me asking, but may I ask how I can remove the blue underline and colour with link text? Also, is it possible to change the centre point of the header? Because I'm looking to add a logo at some point. Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Perhaps you should do a starter course if you do not know a simple thing like changing the colour of a link, or even try googling change link colour css

Comment: @Pete Okay will do, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width:100%` from `li` so menu start from left side

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 100px;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font: Helvetica;
  font-size: 100%;
  outline: 0 none;
}
ul li + li{
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li id="nav-products"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li id="nav-contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li id="nav-about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

or You want menu start from center remove `float:left` from `li` and add `display: inline-block`

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 100px;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font: Helvetica;
  font-size: 100%;
  outline: 0 none;
}

ul li + li{
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li id="nav-products"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li id="nav-contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li id="nav-about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, may I ask what "ul li + li" does?

Comment: It's added `margin-left` in <li> which has immediately come after <li>

Comment: Thanks, now I understand :)